# Comparison test of two series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}.$$ On the proof that this series converges it is compared to $\frac{1}{2n}$ and it is concluded that for all $n: \frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{2n}$ and because $\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges so must also a original series. But for the comparison test the strict inequality must be true for all $n$, no? for $n=1$ the inequality doesn't hold. Can someone help>

Comment: Not at all, the inequality doesn't have to be strict.

Answer (score 3):

No. Actually, if a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of non-negative numbers diverges and if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ is a series such that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):b_n\geqslant a_n,$$then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ diverges too. So, strict inequality is not needed. As matter of fact, it is enough to assume that the inequality $b_n\geqslant a_n$ holds if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: Good idea! I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it must not. Remember that we are interested in the sequence $(S_n)$, called the partial sums of the series $\sum u_k$, such that
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*,\, S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n u_k
$$
where $(u_n)$ is a sequence.
So, what we care about is the behavior of $S_n$ when $n \rightarrow + \infty$.